# Dictionary to custom string format

Tags: string, python-3.x, dictionary, formatting

Right, I have a dictionary like this one:

my_dict = `{'BAM': (1.985, 1.919), 'PLN': (4.509, 4.361),'SEK': (9.929, 9.609), 'CZK': (27.544, 26.544),
             'NOK': (9.2471, 8.9071), 'AUD': (1.4444, 1.4004),
             'HUF': (315.89, 307.09), 'GBP': (0.8639, 0.8399),
             'HRK': (7.6508, 7.4208), 'RUB': (71.9393, 66.5393),
             'USD': (1.0748, 1.0508), 'MKD': (62.11, 60.29),
             'CHF': (1.0942, 1.0602), 'JPY': (121.83, 118.03),
             'BGN': (1.979, 1.925), 'RSD': (124.94, 121.14),
             'DKK': (7.5521, 7.3281), 'CAD': (1.4528, 1.4048)}`

I need to write a function (my_dict, ["GBP", "USD", "RUB", "HRK", "HUF"]) that returns this:

`GBP......0.8639......0.8399
USD......1.0748......1.0508
RUB.....71.9393.....66.5393
HRK......7.6508......7.4208
HUF....315.8900....307.0900`

We are learning how to format string, and I have no idea how to approach this. Any help would be appreciated. It needs to be formatted exactly like this, with all the dots and stuff (without the empty space before GBP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the simpler ways to do what you're asking is to use a 
[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def my_function(dict, list):
    return ["{0}......{1}......{2}".format(item, dict[item][0], dict[item][1])
            for item in list
            if item in dict]
```

`my_function` will return a list of `currency......value......value` items. In fact, you don't even need to create a function:

```
strings = ["{0}......{1}......{2}".format(item, dict[item][0], dict[item][1])
           for item in list
           if item in dict]
```

If however you don't want to use a list comprehension, the same function could look like this:

```
def my_function(dict, list):
    strings = []
    for item in list:
        if item in dict:
            strings.append("{0}......{1}......{2}".format(item, dict[item][0], dict[item][1]))

    return strings
```